# best algorithm to store passwords in 2016

Tags: php, security, web, hash

Actually I read many post related to the algorithm for use like **md5**, **sha1** and so on. But I am still not sure which one is the secure and the best one to use nowadays. I am beginner with web development and I am asking all of the best programmers around the world to teach and show me. I hope you guys can give me the choice and example for using it. Thank You

Comment: The best to use these days is [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) with [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) and there are examples in the PHP Document pages; not to mention on [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing)

Comment: @MarkBaker `password_hash()` isn't an algorithm, it's a function using bcrypt/crypt_blowfish algorithm.

Comment: @Daan - just wanting to avoid confusing an acknowledge beginner with too much information in one go

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will study more about it

Comment: @MalayMuslim - If you are interested in the basics of secure password storing, you may have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Comment: @martinstoeckli Thank you for sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 17):

Incidentally: [How to safely store your users' passwords in 2016](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016).

Your choices are:

- Argon2 (requires PHP 7.2 or a PHP extension)
- Scrypt (requires PHP extension)
- Bcrypt

If you really need to, also feel free to consider PBKDF2.

### The old standby: Bcrypt

Given that you're a beginner, you should be writing your password validation like this:

```
// Creating your hashed password:
$hash = password_hash($userPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Checking a user-supplied password against a stored hash:
if (password_verify($userPassword, $hash)) {
    // Login successful.
    if (password_needs_rehash($hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) {
        // Recalculate a new password_hash() and overwrite the one we stored previously
    }
}
```

Downside to bcrypt:

- Passwords over 72 characters are truncated.
- Passwords with a NUL byte will truncate.

A stop-gap that works around these limitations is built into [Password Lock](https://github.com/paragonie/password_lock): It pre-hashes passwords with SHA384 then base64-encodes the raw hash before passing to PHP's password API.

First, create an encryption key and store it **outside your document root**. (Otherwise, a hacker can just steal the key.)

```
$newKey = \Defuse\Crypto\Key::createNewRandomKey();
file_put_contents(
    '/outside/document/root/enckey.txt',
    $newKey->saveToAsciiSafeString()
);
```

Now, you can use this key in conjunction with your passwords:

```
$key = Key::loadFromAsciiSafeString(
    file_get_contents('/outside/document/root/enckey.txt')
);

// Hashing a password with PasswordLock:
$storeMe = PasswordLock::hashAndEncrypt($_POST['password'], $key);

// Verifying a password with PasswordLock:
if (PasswordLock::decryptAndVerify($_POST['password'], $storeMe, $key)) {
    // Success!
}
```

#### [You can now use Argon2 with `password_hash()` in PHP 7.2](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-08-17-php72-argon2-hash-password.html)

### The new standard: Argon2 (via Libsodium)

Unless you're on PHP 7.2 or higher, you'll need to [install libsodium and the PHP extension](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md#installing-libsodium) to use Argon2. Password hashing is one of the features that is **not** provided by sodium_compat.

```
// Password hashing:
$hash_str = sodium_crypto_pwhash_str(
    $password,
    SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
    SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE
);
// Password verification:
if (sodium_crypto_pwhash_str_verify($hash_str, $password)) {
    // recommended: wipe the plaintext password from memory
    sodium_memzero($password);

    // Password was valid.
} else {
    // recommended: wipe the plaintext password from memory
    sodium_memzero($password);

    // Password was invalid.
}
```

### Intermediate: Scrypt

You'll need [the scrypt extension](https://github.com/DomBlack/php-scrypt) which is available through PECL:

```
pecl install scrypt
echo "extension=scrypt.so" > /etc/php5/mods-available/scrypt.ini
php5enmod scrypt
```

Once that's installed, using it is fairly straightforward:

```
// Hashing:
$hash = \Password::hash($userProvidedPassword);
// Validation:
if (\Password::check($userProvidedPassword, $hash)) {
    // Logged in successfully.
}
```

The only reason to really use scrypt is compatibility; at this point, go with either Argon2 or bcrypt.

#### Acceptable but not Great: PBKDF2

I highly recommend going with [Defuse Security's cross-platform Password Hashing library](https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing) if you need PBKDF2. (You should consider just using `password_*`, however!)

```
$hash = PasswordStorage::create_hash($password);
if (PasswordStorage::verify_password($password, $hash)) {
    // Success
}
```

---

Any of the above choices are *acceptable*. Argon2 is probably the most secure, but it's not widely available in PHP yet. Anything absent from this list should be regarded with a healthy dose of skepticism.

Comment: since you didn't mention phpass (http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) how would you rate it among 2016 hash options?

Comment: PHPass is bcrypt, unless you're on WordPress. Don't use it unless you must; use `password_*` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Important is, that the algorithm offers a **cost factor**, which controls the necessary time to calculate a hash. The more time you can invest in calculating a single hash, the more expensive brute-forcing will become (e.g. [100 Giga MD5 per second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance) vs 10 BCrypt per second).

Today recommended algorithms are BCrypt, PBKDF2 and SCrypt. The algorithm BCrypt is supported by PHP, a wrapper function takes care of the generation of a salt and is future proof.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```