# checking username and password PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a php username and password checker but can't get it to work, here is the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "iphere";
$user = "userhere";
$pass = "passwordhere";
$dbname = "databasehere";

try {
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :name AND password = :password");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($username == $result && $password == $result)
    {
        echo "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not OK";
    }


}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error";
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

It doesn't give any error or anything. It just echoes OK and thats it. By the way i use GET for my another project. So i will change it later.

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: Maybe it's time to `print_r($result)`?

Comment: Never **EVER** store passwords in plain text

Comment: And read a manual what does `setFetchMode` __do__ and what does it __return__

Comment: As an aside, I would encourage you to look at question regarding safe password storage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454203/best-algorithm-to-store-passwords-in-2016

Comment: $password == $result but how this condition satisfy in your mysql query you are selecting only username

Comment: How would `$result` ever be equal to both `$username` _and_ `$password` at the same time…?!

Comment: Thanks to all, i fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is an error, this:

> ```
> $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
> ```

will always be the boolean value `true`.

You then perform this test:

> ```
> if($username == $result && $password == $result)
> ```

Non-blank strings will always be equal to `true`.

---

Count the number of rows returned from the database instead.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it :) Im completely new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the facts that:

- your password is in plaintext
- you're using bindParam for no reason

then the code that I'd use would be something like this (didn't test, beware):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS user_exists FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");

$stmt->execute([':username' => $username, ':password' => $password]);

// This will return the value of first column, our query will always produce 1 row with 1 column
$exists = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 

// If you are using MySQL ND (native driver), then the above result will be 
// accurately represented as an integer so we can use it in an if() statement like this
if($exists)
{
    echo "OK!";
}
else
{
    echo "Not ok!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now it's working :)